# Can there be consistent countable FOL theories having no countable models?

Tags: logic, set-theory, first-order-logic, axiom-of-choice

$\sf LS(\aleph_0)$: Every model $M$ of a first order theory $\sf T$ with countable signature has an elementary submodel $N$ which is at most countable.

Now this theorem is equivalent over axioms of $\sf ZF$ to the axiom of dependet choice $``\sf DC"$.

Now does this mean that in $\sf ZF + \neg DC$, we can have a consistent theorey in a countable signature that doesn't have a countable model?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. If a theory is well-orderable, then it has a well-orderable model satisfying all the usual properties in $\sf ZFC$.

To see why, note that you can code all the thing into a set of ordinals $A$, then in $L[A]$ your theory exists and it is a model of $\sf ZFC$, so the theory has a countable model. But this is upwards absolute to $V$.

Comment: That's a massively overkill argument - just observe that the usual model construction goes through without choice if the theory is well-orderable. (+1 of course, though.)

Comment: Sure, but that's a neater argument.

Comment: can we have first order theories in countable signature that are not well orderable?

Comment: @Zuhair: No. If a theory is countable, the signature is countable. If a signature is countable, there are countably many sentences from whence a theory is born. If a signature is well-orderable, then there are well-orderably many sentences. If you just add symbols, but never ever use them, what's the point of having them?